# What do I need to connect a refrigerator water line?

Tags: water, kitchens, appliances, refrigerator, valve

I currently have  a water valve behind my refrigerator, but it's not hooked up to our current refrigerator. I have no tubing coming out of the valve.  We purchased a new refrigerator and want to hook up a water line to it.  The company we bought it from will bring a water hose with it.  Do I need to do anything else to the valve before they hook up the water hose?

Answer (score 5):

You will need a compression fitting for both ends if you don't already have them.  Often the fridges will come with a plastic supply line but I always like to replace it with a copper one as they last longer and are less prone to damage.

You might also want to verify the valve works correctly.  If it is a piercing-type valve, the often fail and should be replaced with a soldered/compression fitting.